# Add Increment/Decrement with Click function In Bootstrap 4 range slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I have this range slider built with BS and bootstrap-slider.js that is working nicely by dragging:

```
<div class="container range">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">
        <span id="ex6SliderVal">2.5</span>
      </div>
      <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="2.5"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the JS:

```
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjuh62yg/

I would like to also add plus and minus arrows (buttons) to increment and decrement the value with mouse click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `getValue` and `setValue` of bootstrap slider to `increment` and decrement value of your `slider` with `button` click or `+` OR `-` sign in the `demo` i created for you.

In the `increment` you will get the current-value and increase the value by setting the value and adding the value of your slider which is to `0.01` float `number`. To make sure that we are adding the `correct` float `value` we can use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function which ensures that we are adding float `decimal` not straight exact numbers.

In the `decrement` we use the same but in this case we subtract the value of the `slider` and move the backwards for visual effect as well as we update the span text

**Live Demo:**

```js
let mySlider = $("#ex6").slider(); //initiate slider
let spanText = $("#ex6SliderVal") //span text
let addValue = 0.01; //add float to increment 

$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
  spanText.text(slideEvt.value)
});
 
//Increment
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  let currValue = mySlider.slider('getValue'); //get current value
  mySlider.slider('setValue', parseFloat(currValue + addValue).toFixed(2)) //increment value of slider
  spanText.text(currValue) //show span
});

//Decrement 
$(".subtract").on("click", function() {
  let currValue = mySlider.slider('getValue'); //get current value
  mySlider.slider('setValue', parseFloat(currValue - addValue).toFixed(2)) //decrement value of slider
  spanText.text(currValue) //show span
});
```

```css
.range {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#ex6CurrentSliderValLabel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.slider.slider-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider.slider-horizontal:before {}

.subtract {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6%;
}

.add {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 6%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js" integrity="sha512-f0VlzJbcEB6KiW8ZVtL+5HWPDyW1+nJEjguZ5IVnSQkvZbwBt2RfCBY0CBO1PsMAqxxrG4Di6TfsCPP3ZRwKpA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" integrity="sha512-3q8fi8M0VS+X/3n64Ndpp6Bit7oXSiyCnzmlx6IDBLGlY5euFySyJ46RUlqIVs0DPCGOypqP8IRk/EyPvU28mQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<div class="container range">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">
        <span id="ex6SliderVal">0</span>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-minus subtract" aria-hidden="true"></i>

      <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="0" />
      <i class="fa fa-plus add" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! There is only one small thing, the first increment click is not registering properly. It is also not registering when you drag the number and then you click the increment (+). It's not a big deal though.

Answer (score -1):

Hacky and needs refactoring, but it works

```js
var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
var valueConteiner = document.getElementById("ex6SliderVal");

slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
  valueConteiner.textContent = sliderValue;
});

function incrementDecrement(el, value) {
  let currentValue = slider.getValue();

  if(el[0].id === "plus") {
    slider.setValue(currentValue + value)
  } else if(el[0].id === "minus") {
    slider.setValue(currentValue - value)
  }

  valueConteiner.textContent = slider._state.value[0];  
}

$('.container.range')
  .off('click', '#plus, #minus')
  .on('click', '#plus, #minus', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('id').match('plus')) {
      incrementDecrement($(this), 1) // second parameter determines increment step
    } else {
      incrementDecrement($(this), 0.1) // second parameter determines decrement step
    }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">

<div class="container range">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">
        <span id="ex6SliderVal">2.5</span>
      </div>
      <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="2.5"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="plus">+</button>
  <button id="minus">-</button>
</div>
```